# Do I need any approval from Facebook/twitter team to add `og|twitter` meta tag in my site?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, oembed, twitter-card

I would like to add embedded representation of my site's link on third party sites. So, I'm adding `oEmbed` link to my site. Also I'm adding `og` and `twitter` meta tags to my site to make the embedded content visible in Facebook and twitter sites.

Do I need to get any approval from `Facebook` or `Twitter` team to make my `og` and `twitter` tags visible in their site?

If no approval is needed how `og` or `twitter` tag is visible to them? Or how should I get approval for adding meta tags to my site?

Any advise is much appreciated ! Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Similarly for `oEmbed` - does adding oEmbed link tag in my page's html alone is enough huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, feel free to use it at will.** In fact it is highly recommended.

[Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) is an open API of optional meta tags you could choose to add to your website to *enhance* crawlers.

You can check how facebook crawls your page or even force a rescrape using [their debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

The equivalent debugger for Twitter is [this](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator). They call them `Cards` and you can find more about them [here](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview).

Comment: My pleasure, hun.